# Make a position absolute element appear like it is still in the document flow?

Tags: css

I have a div which is position absolute causing the proceeding content to sit over it which is understandable, I was wondering how I can have the div remain as position: absolute but have the content continuing as if the div was still in the document flow? Would this call for a padding bottom trick on the absolute content?

**HTML**

```
    <div class="content">
  <h1>Heading</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet provident aperiam consequuntur veniam repellendus eaque repudiandae, modi architecto aut fugit esse nostrum quidem quo molestiae quasi! Sed facilis, molestias perspiciatis.</p>

  <div class="absolute">
    <h2>Position absolute content</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatem distinctio hic quidem vero tenetur ad mollitia voluptas libero, voluptates dolore quasi doloremque id cum! Facilis qui similique facere commodi quisquam.</p>
  </div>

  <div>
    <h2>Heading 2</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium voluptas non dolor facilis natus nam. Voluptas commodi illum aut quasi voluptatibus cupiditate doloribus at officia voluptates. Reiciendis placeat delectus repellendus.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.absolute {
  position: absolute;
}
```

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mz41jzqd/

Comment: so why is it absolute if it needs to be within the document flow? it's a bit like saying "i want it to be red but how can i make it green"

Comment: That content will actually be a table that uses iscroll and requires the scrolling container to be position: absolute.

Comment: you can set a margin/padding on the top like you suggest, the only problem is you basically need to know size of the content around it ahead of time. otherwise do it with javascript

Comment: yeah I was hoping there would be a plain CSS solution without having to set heights or margins with JS with listeners etc

Comment: @MrLister you would actually need to do margin-top on the element below or the element itself for this example

Comment: Do you want to give it `position:absolute` in order to animate it?

Comment: @aw04 Yes, sorry, you are right. For pentinence, I updated the OP's fiddle with the JavaScript I meant. https://jsfiddle.net/mz41jzqd/2/

Comment: Hey, this is kind of what I need to achieve in terms of flow, I have a table that I need to add horizontal scroll using iscroll and its wrapper requires position: absolute https://jsfiddle.net/6sh2eykk/

Comment: You can add a placeholder div. Something [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/s4jt9Lhv/).

Comment: The simplest solution is to create a javascript function that measures height of `.absolute` and updates `margin-top` of element below it. This should be run on `window.load`, `window.resize` and `.absolute.resize`. Do you want me to add such a function as an answer or have you got this?

Comment: Could you demonstrate this please Andrei?

Comment: it's exactly what @MrLister created above ^, you may just need to modify it a bit for your actual code (ie the second fiddle it is nested)

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't follow the link. Yes, basically it's the same thing. It's just in plain JavaScript. I did ask before writing it and explained what I was going to do :). Heh. A Happy New Year everyone!

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu I wasn't criticizing, my comment was meant for OP. No problem with adding it as an answer, I'm the one who upvoted

Comment: Actually, he only runs it on page load. This means the margin doesn't get updated on `resize`. It should be wrapped in a function and bound to `resize` of the `.absolute` element, at least.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function updateTopMargin(){
  var abs = $('.absolute').eq(0);
  abs.next().css({'margin-top':abs.outerHeight()+'px'});
}
$(window).on('load resize', updateTopMargin);
$('.absolute').on('resize', updateTopMargin);
```

```css
.absolute {
  position: absolute;
}
.absolute + * {
  padding-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <h1>Heading</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet provident aperiam consequuntur veniam repellendus eaque repudiandae, modi architecto aut fugit esse nostrum quidem quo molestiae quasi! Sed facilis, molestias perspiciatis.</p>

  <div class="absolute">
    <h2>Position absolute content</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatem distinctio hic quidem vero tenetur ad mollitia voluptas libero, voluptates dolore quasi doloremque id cum! Facilis qui similique facere commodi quisquam.</p>
  </div>

  <div>
    <h2>Heading 2</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium voluptas non dolor facilis natus nam. Voluptas commodi illum aut quasi voluptatibus cupiditate doloribus at officia voluptates. Reiciendis placeat delectus repellendus.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```